# typescript calling a function every specific time

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on a mobile app using ionic and typescript.
I want to update the location on the user every 10 min for example

So my idea is to call a function every 10 min like this

```
function yourFunction(){
  // do whatever you like here
  setTimeout(yourFunction, (1000 * 60) * 10);
  }

  yourFunction();
}
```

So, is this ok? I mean is this function will execute even if the application is not running? Like for example I am using another, is this function going to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong, as each time `yourFunction` run it calls itself again, which would result in infinite recursion.

A better way to do this is to use `setInterval` and outside the function you are calling itself like this

```
function yourFunction(){
    // Do the stuffs here
}

var theRunner = setInterval( function(){
    yourFunction();
}, (1000 * 60 * 10));
```

Comment: But what is the difference here? you are invoking the same method every specific time and same I do? I could not understand

Comment: You were calling `yourFunction` inside of itself outside of the `setTimeout`, that is where the problem was

Comment: Oh, I think that wasn't the case, you left an extra curly bracket at the end that is why I thought you were calling the function inside itself. I think your could would have worked properly still a better way would be to use `setInterval`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function that does exactly this, and allows you to cancel the interval as well:

```
function yourFunction() { console.log("Repeading"); }
let id = setInterval(yourFunction, 100)
clearInterval(id); // top stop the repetition
```

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to use

```
setInterval(yourFunction, time_in_ms);
```

but your solution should work aswell if you do it like this:

```
function yourFunction() {
   setTimeout(yourFunction, time_in_ms);
} 
yourFunction();
```